# Create two nodes from webform submission

Tags: nodes, webforms

I have webform with many fields.
And I need to create two nodes after webform submission.
First node would have some values from the webform.
And second node would have other values from the same webform.

How can I do this?
(rules? hooks?)

Would be using [Webform Default Fields](https://drupal.org/project/webform_default_fields) or [Webform report](https://drupal.org/project/webform_report) the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Rules.

Here's a link. [Using webform rules to create node after webform submission](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99292/using-webform-rules-to-create-node-after-webform-submission)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried [Rules + Rules_Webform] at simplytest.me, but I cant see how can I set node field equal to webform submitted value. Have I use Token module?

Comment: I've got it! **[Rules + Rules_Webform + Token]** made the miracle. And ReadMe for Rules_Webform explains how to use tokens. ty

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :)