# Rule to create a Node from a Webform Submission

Tags: nodes, rules, webforms

Using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) with [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) enabled, how would I make a new node after a webform submission and use the submitted values as field values in the node?

In short, **how do I turn webform submissions into nodes using Rules.**

I've set up the Rule like this:

[image: Rules]

Where do I go from here? I can't seem to find a way to move webform submission values into the node's fields.

---

**Please note:** I have read "[Using webform rules to create node after webform submission](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99292/using-webform-rules-to-create-node-after-webform-submission)" and "[How to create a node with submissions of a webform?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80022/how-to-create-a-node-with-submissions-of-a-webform)". Unfortunately, neither address my question.

Comment: The whole point of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80022/how-to-create-a-node-with-submissions-of-a-webform is that you do not need to take the extra step via Rules and Webforms. Create the nodes directly.

Comment: @Jeroen Thank. But is it possible to do it the way I've outlined?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/199821/39516), and my answer to it. Not sure if your question is a duplicate of that question, but possibly my answer to that question also works for your question, no?

Comment: @Jeroen, it's often necessary to provide a more user friendly version of a form. I tend to use a mix of node/add and entity forms.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, this is the right answer. I'd add that sometimes it is necessary to force save a node after creating it in the rule for some entity reference (OG mainly) things to work.

Comment: And finally, when it's very complicated and standard rules won't work, you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_session_vars to add values to $_SESSIONs and create a second rule for when a node is created. You add conditions for the Sessions and then delete them at the end of the rule. I've had to do this only twice.

Comment: hey @NiallMurphy ... which answer do you mean by that "this is the right answer"? Also, didn't know about that session vars module, merci for the hint! I'm trying to picture appropriate use-cases for it. Think of something like some Rules scenario related to anonymous users (where you can't use a custom user field since user is not logged in). would that be a good case to use this interesting module? Otherwise, why not post a sef answered question containing an appropriate case?

Comment: I mean your link to your answer about "entity has field". I actually have a broken collarbone and can only type extremely slowly with my bad hand so I'm avoiding full answers or extra typing :p There are many uses of the module that can create very interesting add-on rules that would otherwise be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is something I learned about using webform data in Rules, which may help you to get this to work ... (assuming this question is about D7).

You have access to all ***labels*** and all ***values*** of any field of a webform, ie:

- `[data:MachineFieldName-title]` contains the **Label** of a field with machine name MachineFieldName.
- `[data:MachineFieldName-value]` contains the **Value** of a field with machine name MachineFieldName

So try to use similar tokens.

For way more details on this, and a prototype rule about this, refer to the answer to "[How to create a node from a Webform using rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199821/how-to-create-a-node-from-a-webform-using-rules/199825#199825)":

- the *1st attempt* relates to using "Entity has field" (which doesn't work for Webform).
- the *2nd attempt* explains what to do in case of Webform.

**Note**: if your target field is a multi value field, using "Set a data value" is completely wrong. Instead you need to use an action like "Add item to a list". Refer to my answer to "[How to set multiple values to an unlimited Term Refence field with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/220892/39516)" for way more details about "*Add item to a list*".

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the missing piece. Thanks. Seems like a good place to start, anyway. What if the destination field on the node is a select list?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback (and accept). Not sure how to correctly understand your question in your last comment. Actually what's the problem, or what's stopping you from getting that to work? Maybe it's worth posting a new question?

Comment: This works when the destination field in the node is a text field. I have one that's a select list. The source is an identical select list in the webform, but I can't get the webform selection value populate the node's select value.